# How to login into salesforce through android smartphone?

Tags: android, salesforce

I have installed  SDK and when I am executing a sample application in eclipse I am getting an error while logging into salesforce like this

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL `https://login.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2Fsetup%2Fsecur%2FRemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp%3Fsource%3Dl86Hcy6qEKtWNqzXVErZDlmcRQs0D_HBE55MLVuP3x8t5wXkyHYyrVx2Xb5JoWzyVOJrnTqMMaWy_Sfo0mo2n3jvu8IfPosBnmPsp1pafeNjQPGSngZvcMpAyNsTC62PxX8rVEu.GK3O6Y3FWwqTYFhIu97eeHIM4ca76Rj0rms8wRYPaZ_Bn7qxXKSKMr9ZfcNx3ypToLFS0IGq51_Ud09ujxJLb4N82smXIx37QNpk1hMmwZSSg7NYgF6VRdhQDfWZxb85wCOHMy9aNm0zOes_XhH3xWqL28AvaSP4_NC4esWw_0TkP51agEmNZuFoz64RqwxExwiKtXhaNBbhTTaePLkdlCT6aXnmIMTSkoekmQZqjCBsU74H8dgWjZHbZTpBhWXVbM5sr0f3JnWlmpKAJWYXym7s%253D%26display%3Dtouch%26sdtd%3D1&display=touch&sdtd=1`

from frame with URL `https://www.salesforce.com/login-messages/messages.html?r=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.salesforce.com%2Fsetup%2Fsecur%2FRemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp%3Fsource%3Dl86Hcy6qEKtWNqzXVErZDlmcRQs0D_HBE55MLVuP3x8t5wXkyHYyrVx2Xb5JoWzyVOJrnTqMMaWy_Sfo0mo2n3jvu8IfPosBnmPsp1pafeNjQPGSngZvcMpAyNsTC62PxX8rVEu.GK3O6Y3FWwqTYFhIu97eeHIM4ca76Rj0rms8wRYPaZ_Bn7qxXKSKMr9ZfcNx3ypToLFS0IGq51_Ud09ujxJLb4N82smXIx37QNpk1hMmwZSSg7NYgF6VRdhQDfWZxb85wCOHMy9aNm0zOes_XhH3xWqL28AvaSP4_NC4esWw_0TkP51agEmNZuFoz64RqwxExwiKtXhaNBbhTTaePLkdlCT6aXnmIMTSkoekmQZqjCBsU74H8dgWjZHbZTpBhWXVbM5sr0f3JnWlmpKAJWYXym7s%253D%26display%3Dtouch%26sdtd%3D1&`noroundedcorner. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Execeptions:

11-11 11:23:07.239: E/AndroidRuntime(366): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.String.isEmpty
11-11 11:23:07.239: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at com.salesforce.androidsdk.ui.OAuthWebviewHelper$BaseFinishAuthFlowTask.onPostExecute(OAuthWebviewHelper.java:378)
11-11 11:23:07.239: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at com.salesforce.androidsdk.ui.OAuthWebviewHelper$BaseFinishAuthFlowTask.onPostExecute(OAuthWebviewHelper.java:1)
11-11 11:23:07.239: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
11-11 11:23:07.239: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
11-11 11:23:07.239: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
11-11 11:23:07.239: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-11 11:23:07.239: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-11 11:23:07.239: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-11 11:23:07.239: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 11:23:07.239: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-11 11:23:07.239: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-11 11:23:07.239: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-11 11:23:07.239: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I think this is  a security related error is any permissions required to login through mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore those errors/exceptions. If you are trying to **import sample applications provided by salesforce sdk**, you must be able to login as you will be navigated to login page when you run your app.

As far as permissions are concerned, you need following common permissions we use in Android applications

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

But still no luck with creating our own application and running.